# Design for an outdoor swing to hold at least 300lbs

Tags: load-bearing, post, swing

I am trying to build a super strong swing for my big kids and adults to use. I know it's preferable, but I would like to avoid an A-frame design because I just don't like the look.

If I sink two 6"x6"x14' posts 4' deep on each side, with a 6"x6"x10' beam sandwiched between them at the top, will that hold?

Comment: I would ere an the side  of caution, Go six feet deep, or more (*300 pounds swinging side to side is a lot of lateral force*)  and use a 6"x8" x 10' beam.

Comment: There would be huge horizontal force pulling the frame, and easily turn it over. I'll extend Alaska Man's response to include concrete pier.

Comment: Think about if you *have ever seen* a swing, even for little kids, built like that. The answer must guide your destiny, Padawan; you are not a Jedi yet...

Comment: I actually have seen swings built that way, that is how I got the idea. If I do an A- frame, will 4"x4"x12' pressure treated posts and a 4"x6"x10' pressure treated beam, be strong enough to support 400 lbs swinging?